# South American Indians: Incan vs Inca?

Tags: ethnonyms

Reading a little about the Inca people of South America and I see that most commonly the word Inca is used instead of Incan, e.g.:

The **Inca** Empire vs The **Incan** Empire

My natural instinct would be to say Incan.  Is Incan wrong here?  Why is Inca usually used instead of Incan?

For reference and more examples see this article: http://www.britannica.com/EBchecked/topic/284517/Inca

Comment: Was there actually a place called *Inca*? If you used *Incan* for *Incan empire* or *Incan people*, how would you use *Inca*?

Comment: @WS2 This one _is_ a plural count noun: _The Inca established their capital at Cuzco (Peru) in the 12th century._ [Encyclopedia Britannica]. But then so, apparently, is _dogs_ in _dogs home_.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Ah. But do you say *The Battersea dogs' home*, or *The Battersea dog's home*. (I didn't know he'd been away) Their website shows their name with no apostrophes: http://www.battersea.org.uk/

Comment: You _write_ it the way they do. If they choose to go with the modern trend of dropping apostrophes in constructions showing associative rather than true possessive connections, that's their prerogative. _Childrens_ and _mens_ are now words (and some working mens clubs have used _mens_ for quite a time). We have Manchester and Cheshire Dogs' Home and Leigh Dogs and Cats Home in Greater Manchester.

Answer (score 2):

Incan is a variant (not very common) of Inca.

[Inca Empire](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inca_Empire):

> - The Inca Empire (Quechua: Tawantinsuyu, lit. "The Four Regions"), also known as the Inka Empire or Incan Empire, was the largest empire in pre-Columbian America. The administrative, political, and military center of the empire was located in Cusco in modern-day Peru. The Inca civilization arose from the highlands of Peru sometime in the early 13th century, and the last Inca stronghold was conquered by the Spanish in 1572.

[Etymology](https://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=Inca&searchmode=none):

> - 1590s, from Spanish Inga (1520s), from Quechea Inca, literally "lord, king." Technically, only of the high Inca, but it was used widely for "man of royal blood."

[Incan](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/Incan) :

(also Inkan )

> - adj.
>     Of or relating to the Inca, their civilization, or their language.
>     n.
>
>   1. An Inca.
>   2. Quechua.

[Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Inca%2CIncan&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2CInca%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3BInca%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Binca%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BINCA%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2CIncan%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3BIncan%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bincan%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BINCAN%3B%2Cc0): Inca vs Incan.